# Configure GeoNetwork with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, geonetwork, configuration

For testing purposes, I deployed geonetwork 3.0.1 on tomcat7 and ubuntu 14.04 with default configuration, especially h2 database.

Now I wanted to switch to postgres and followed the instructions found on several sources, e.g. [here](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/maintainer-guide/installing/configuring-database.html):

I edited the file `/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml`, enabling the line `<import resource="../config-db/postgres.xml"/>`

After that, I created a postgresql user and database 'geonetwork' in postgresql.

Then I changed the default database password in `/WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties` with the information from the created database and database user and restarted tomcat.

I read [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/create-scripts-in-3-0-td5205280.html) that after configuring this information and starting geonetwork, there would be run sql scripts automatically to initialize database structure for geonetwork.

I cannot find anything changed from my setup with the h2 database before. When I access localhost:8080/geonetwork, there are still layer information that I created in h2 database before. I would guess they would not be transferred.

How can I check, if I successfully started geonetwork with the underlying postgres database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it work now. This was pretty easy actually. I had to restart tomcat by using `/bin/shutdown.sh` and `startup.sh` instead of `service tomcat7 restart.`

After deploying geonetwork.war from scratch, my geonetwork UI was reset and database was filled with tables, so I guess that's it.

Comment: Some distributions think that the restart option  in tomcat is not advisable. But in any case, restart should work if and only if the webapps/geonetwork folder had the modified files updated.